# Sql if else condition is not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have following sql embedded in c# code.

It's a search query and searching is based on city and address.

the query as follow,

```
string sql = "declare @v int;set @v=-1;declare @st varchar(1000);";
    sql += "set @st='select PLACEID,LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1000),description),500)+''...'' as des1,LOCATIONCITY,ADDRESS,DateT,RENT from infoone  where '";

    int x = 0;
    string ft = "";
    string sql1 = "";

    sql += "; Select @v= count(address) from infoone  where(";

    foreach (string s in str)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            ft += " " + s;


            sql += "(address like '%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%')";
            sql1 += "(address like ''%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%'')";


        }
        else
        {
            ft += " " + s;
            sql += " OR (address like '%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%')";//ft.Remove(0, 1)
            sql1 += " OR (address like ''%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%'')";//ft.Remove(0, 1)


        }
        x++;
    }
    sql += "); if @v > 0 begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + "'+ 'and ('; end else begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + "'+ 'or (';  end ";
    sql1 = "";
    x = 0;
    sql += "; Select @v= count(locationcity) from infoone  where(";
    foreach (string s in str)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            sql += "(locationcity like '%" + s + "%') ";
            sql1 += "(locationcity like ''%" + s + "%'') ";
        }
        else
        {
            sql += " OR (locationcity like '%" + s + "%') ";
            sql1 += " OR (locationcity like ''%" + s + "%'') ";
        }
        x++;
    }
    sql += "); if @v>0 begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + ")'+' and ('; end else begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + ")'+ 'or ('; end  ";
    x = 0;
    sql1 = "";
    ft = "";
    //sql += " and (";
    sql += "Select @v= count(address) from infoone  where(";
    foreach (string s in str)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            ft += " " + s;


            sql += "(address like '%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%')";
            sql1 += "(address like ''%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%'')";


        }
        else
        {
            ft += " " + s;
            sql += " OR (address like '%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%')";//ft.Remove(0, 1)
            sql1 += " OR (address like ''%" + ft.Remove(0, 1) + "%'')";//ft.Remove(0, 1)


        }
        x++;
    }
    sql += "); if @v>0 begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + ")'; end else begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + ")';  end  execute(@st);";
```

The problem is with the following line

```
sql += "); if @v > 0 begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + "'+ 'and ('; end else begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + "'+ 'or (';  end ";
```

The sql variable @v is assigned like this,

```
select @v=count(address) from infoone where address like '%edmonton%'
```

In above line, @v should get '0' and I checked it separately. But still the if condition runs in following code (not runs the else condition which it should)

```
sql += "); if @v>0 begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + ")'+' and ('; end else begin set @st=@st+'" + sql1 + ")'+ 'or ('; end  ";
x = 0;
```

The query that generates in the end is following, but again the query is executed using sql execute(...). And the main sql login is not included in query,

```
declare @v int;set @v=-1;declare @st varchar(1000);
 set @st='select PLACEID,LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1000),description),500)+''.'' as            des1,LOCATIONCITY,ADDRESS,DateT,RENT from infoone  where ';
  Select @v= count(address) from infoone  where((address like '%main%')
   OR
    (address like '%main street%')
     OR (address like '%main street edmonton%'));
      if @v > 0 begin set @st=@st+'(address like ''%main%'') 
      OR (address like ''%main street%'') OR (address like ''%main street        edmonton%'')'+
       'and ('; end else begin set @st=@st+'(address like ''%main%'') OR (address like     ''%main street%'')
        OR (address like ''%main street edmonton%'')'+ 'or (';  end ; 
        Select @v= count(locationcity) from infoone  where((locationcity like '%main%') 
         OR (locationcity like '%street%')  OR (locationcity like '%edmonton%') );
          if @v>0 begin set @st=@st+'(locationcity like ''%main%'')  OR (locationcity  like ''%street%'')  
          OR (locationcity like ''%edmonton%'') )'+' and ('; end else begin set     @st=@st+'(locationcity like ''%main%'')  
          OR (locationcity like ''%street%'')  OR (locationcity like ''%edmonton%'') )'+
           'or ('; end  Select @v= count(address) from infoone  where((address like     '%main%') 
           OR (address like '%main street%') OR (address like '%main street edmonton%'));
            if @v>0 begin set @st=@st+'(address like ''%main%'') OR (address like ''%main street%'') 
            OR (address like ''%main street edmonton%''))'; end else begin set   @st=@st+'(address like ''%main%'') 
            OR (address like ''%main street%'') OR (address like ''%main street edmonton%''))';  end  execute(@st);
```

Please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong,

Thanks

Comment: Did you check what is it returning at the end? I mean query.

Comment: yes that's how I came to a point to say that "if @v > 0" condition is giving true even when the @v should be equals to 0

Comment: Can you paste the query only i.e sql statement ? Its difficult to guess whether there is any syntax error is in this or previous lines ..

Comment: @Rafay I have updated question with query but again lots of logic is not included in the finally generated query

Comment: I dont see any syntax errors .. Try Hardcoding the value for @v in start just to check the flow ..

Comment: I believe it's possible for `@v` to be `NULL`, instead of `0`. Can you print out the actual value of `@v`? Oh, and your indenting is off, which makes the code very hard to read and understand.

Comment: Not about your question, but just a good hint: Use StringBuilder to build your SQL string instead of relying on String.operator+=.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're query is saying if @v > 0 [Operation A] else [Operation B]. You're expecting @v == 0, but it's still performing [Operation A] instead of [Operation B]?

> In above line, @v should get '0' and I checked it separately. But still the if condition runs in following code (not runs the else condition which it should)

If [Operation B] should be performed when @v does not equal the default of -1, you probably want it written as

```
if @v>=0 then begin...
```